# No me sale la nueva base de datos creada

Tags: base-de-datos, cmd, docker, pgadmin

Cuando creo una base de datos en `pgAdmin`, voy al cmd para comprobar desde el contenedor que si se creo la base de datos y trato de ejecutar el comando:

```
docker exec -it (nombre del contenedor) psql -U (nombre del usuario)
```

Paso siguiente, entro al contenedor:

```
postgres = #
```

y escribo la opción `\l` para ver las lista de bases de datos que tengo. Pero, no me aparece la que acabo de crear. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Acabe de observar que en la base de datos, la nueva aparece con status de "idle" ¿saben como convertirla en "active"?